# How to disconnect the connection with Connection Manager in WEC7

Tags: c++, network-programming, windows-ce

I'm developing an application that shows available wifi network and allow to connect/disconnection on windows compact 7(x86).

I need to use the Connection Manager APIs because it includes [Connection Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg156531(v=winembedded.70).aspx) in the OS design.

I can add a connection config with [`CmAddConnectionConfig`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg158287(v=winembedded.70).aspx) and connect with [`CmAcquireConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg159283(v=winembedded.70).aspx) successfully. But I did not find a function which can disconnect the target connection. I've tried the function [`CmReleaseConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg158466(v=winembedded.70).aspx), but it always returns `CMRE_INVALID_CONNECTION`.

There is limited information about Connection Manager in Internet and I found somebody met the [same problem](http://quabr.com/29223081/cmacquireconnection-function-returns-cmre-connection-acquire-failed-help-me).

I'm working on it for about three days. It would be appreciated if you can help me to solve it or give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As `CmReleaseConnection` cannot work as expected, I will use `CmDeleteConnectionConfig` for deleting and then create another network profile without doing the connection. I found this solution from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd36a50f-df07-4cd7-ac3b-94a1201ba4ee/cmacquireconnection-returns-cmreconnectionacquirefailed-help-me-manage-network-connections?forum=winembplatdev).

Comment: Thanks for this advice. It worked perfectly first time.